# Obtain value of $p$ such that $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$.

Tags: real-analysis

> $$f(x) =\begin{cases}
> x^p\sin(\frac{1}{x}),  & x \neq 0 \\
> 0, & x=0
> \end{cases}
> $$ Obtain value of $p$ such that $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$.

Answer provided in book is, $p>0$. But if $x \to 0$ and we choose $p=0.001$, will  $f(x) \to 0$?

Comment: We are asked about continuity.  While $\sin(1/x)$ wiggles wildly as $x\to 0$, it is a bounded factor of $f(x)$.  So...  Also a more careful statement of the problem would ask that $x$ approach zero from above, or replace $x^p$ with $|x|^p$ in the definition.

Comment: Yes it will tend to 0 for $p=0.001$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $|\sin(1/x)|\leq 1$, so $|x^{p}\sin(1/x)|\leq|x|^{p}$, if $p>0$, then $|x|^{p}\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: if we choose $x=p=0.001$ the $|0.001^{0.001}| = 0.99..$ why is it not approaching $0$?

Comment: The $p$ is fixed, $x$ varies to $0$, you cannot mix up $p$ and $x$ together.